# Status variable

Tags: c#, winforms, variables

I'm programming a windows application (C#) that can only have 3 forms open.
When I click on the button of form1, form2 will open but it only open once.

I don't know why this is happening.

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

This is my code of form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool form2Opend = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!form2Opend)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
            f2.Show();
            form2Opend = true;
            string data = this.textBox1.Text;
            f2.TextInTextBox(data);
        }
    }

    public void TextInTextBox(string text)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = tekst;
    }

    public void putStatusToOff()
    {
        this.form2Opend = false;
    }
}
```

And here is my code from form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    private Form1 f1;

    public Form2(Form1 giveToForm)
    {
        f1 = giveToForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void TextInTextBox(string tekst)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dataFromForm2 = this.textBox1.Text;
        f1.TextInTextBox(dataFromForm2);
        f1.putStatusToOff();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't know how"? Does it not work, or is that not your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `button1_Click` method you check a status variable `form2Opend` and only open the form if this variable is set to `false`. If you want multiple instances of `Form2` you have to remove that check:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
    f2.Show();
    string data = this.textBox1.Text;
    f2.TextInTextBox(data);
}
```

Comment: Thans but i want that you can only open form2 3 times. Is there a way that you can make a couter of that check?

Comment: Yes. You need an integer to keep track of the open windows and you put your check around the code in button1_Click back in - but this time you check if less windows are open than are allowed.